# How to make these tabs work?

Tags: javascript

I'm in a process of learning JS and decided to try to write a simple tabs from scratch.

I have two functions. One for adding class `'active'` to each tab and another one for triggering this function by clicking on `li` in navigation

Here is my code
https://codepen.io/Allan11/pen/Bzvxya

Problem is that class toggels doesn't seem to work the right way.  Could you show me the right direction on how to fix it or maybe just my approach to these functions is wrong and there is a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write this this way you need to catch the element that the click event was raised on by putting a parameter in your handler and looking at the `srcElement` on this.  This will tell you which of your `li` items was clicked.  However, then you will need to find a way to identify which content belongs to this li item and assign the .active class to it, and remove the class from all the others.  I personally would use a shared class or a data item on the li to do this.

However, all of this seems like trying to do something that already exists perfectly well in the jQuery and jQuery UI frameworks.  Unless you have a really good reason for re-inventing the wheel, I would just use jQuery UI.